# ERROR in [default] new-user.component.ts:21:4 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working through the angular-for-rails-developer book and am at 'Getting Angular2-Token to register a user'

My new-user.component.ts and app.module.ts match that in the book.  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Here's the code:
app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';

import { HomeLibraryRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewUserComponent } from './new-user/new-user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewUserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HomeLibraryRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [Angular2TokenService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

new-user/new-user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Angular2TokenService  } from 'angular2-token';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-user',
  templateUrl: './new-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-user.component.css']
})
export class NewUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _tokenService: Angular2TokenService) {
    this._tokenService.init({
      registerAccountPath: '/api/auth'
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  register() {
    this._tokenService.registerAccount(
      'test@example.com',
      'password',
      'password'
    );
  }
}
```

In webstorm, the _tokenService  init and registerAccount methods are being listed as unresolved.

Comment: It's not helping, Can you add your code here?

Comment: Sounds like you're calling a function with too many/few arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  register() {
    this._tokenService.registerAccount({
      email: 'test@example.com',
      password: 'password',
      passwordConfirmation: 'password'
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I would try this. It looks like the function signature for [registerAccount](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token#registeraccount) has been changed since I wrote that part of the book (and my book needs to be updated).

Comment: Thanks!  I stared right at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-token#signin and missed the change.